# Assigning result object inside FileReader to variable

Tags: javascript

Here is the console log for my `reader` variable. I want to know what the call is for the `reader`>`FileReader`>`result` value would be.

```
console.log(reader);
```

---

```
FileReader {}
    error: null
    onabort: null
    onerror: null
    onload: null
    onloadend: null
    onloadstart: null
    onprogress: null
    readyState: 2
    result: "_id,number,date,duration,type,new,name,numbertype,numberlab...
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand the question, but if the reader is a FileReader Object, and that you didn't call one of its `readAs...` methods, `reader.result` is null.

Comment: And reading your question's title again, you probably just want to fill your variable in the `onload` event of the reader, which will fire once you called one of the `readAs...` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If the output of reader that you have specified is correct then

`reader>FileReader>result` will result in `undefined` as `result` is not inside `FileReader`

as per your log your object is something like this

```
var reader = { 
  FileReader: {}, 
  error: null, 
  result: "_id,number,date,duration"
}
```

to get the result you need to do `reader.result`